# Field Set overlaps region in Edit Forms

Tags: forms

I'm using the simplecorp theme https://www.drupal.org/project/simplecorp but I suspect that this issue translates to other themes as well.

In the edit forms, the fields sets seem to overlap into teh next region to the right.  Is there a way to set teh correct widths on the fields sets?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting CSS rule width:100% on the element that breaks out of the flow (not necessarily the field sets, but one of its parents)

Comment: Yes. I've gone up the divs and tried to apply widths with no affect.  One thing I didnt mention is I am using field groups and have horizontal tabs.

Comment: Have you looked at the CSS position property? And I would also just make sure that the html tags are properly matched. View and copy the source of the html in your browser, then run it through an online markup validator.